# Root of the name Aharon

Tags: hebrew, names, tanach, etymology

What is the etymology of the name Aharon? The only serious site I've found that proposes an etymology is [this](http://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/203/Q3/), but I'm hoping for a more classical source, i.e. Chazal or Rishonim.

Comment: Translation: Aaron

Comment: @Double AA - Pure genius :|

Comment: i'll refrain from saying that it means "beloved"...you know, as in "aharon? aharon chaviv"

Comment: Wouldn't the etymology come from the root רן i.e. רינה? It means to erupt in song חכמות ברחוב תרומה and רני פלט are two פסוקים that illustrate the outward erupting component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source given there, Otzar Midrashim, is an anthology of midrashic works from different periods. In this case, the information comes from a work entitled [Divrei ha-Yamim le-Moshe Rabbeinu](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2585&pgnum=84), which is of unknown date and authorship, but at any rate predates the Aruch (11th century - beginning of the era of the Rishonim), which quotes this etymology (under [s.v. אהרן](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42537&pgnum=13)). [Among other Rishonim, Ibn Ezra (to Ex. 2:22 and 4:20) mentions it but dismisses it as a reliable source; Rashbam to Ex. 4:9 refers to it obliquely (as "ספרים החיצוניים") and likewise rejects the story told there about Moshe's speech defect, though to Num. 12:1 (thanks to jake for this reference) he accepts the story from there about Moshe's rule in Cush; and Yalkut Shimoni uses material from it without reservation.]

Kabbalistically, [Seder Hadoros](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&pgnum=99) quotes a couple of sources who associate the name אהרן with הרן (Avraham's brother), and say that Haran's soul was reincarnated in Aharon.